# Program to list disk space used by Adobe programs

Tags: windows, disk-analysis

I am looking for a program running on Microsoft Windows that can list the disk space used by Adobe programs, ideally split by folder. Any license or price is fine.

I am aware of [AcroSize](https://archive.org/details/acrosize), but it is limited to Adobe Acrobat.

[image]